# Why does two of my questions have 10K views though when you click on the question itself it has less?

Tags: support, questions

I have two questions:
[Spy movie where recruits are tested by flooding their dormitory](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75082/spy-movie-where-recruits-are-tested-by-flooding-their-dormitory)

and:

[How do they film someone being stabbed with a weapon that goes all the way through?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71247/how-do-they-film-someone-being-stabbed-with-a-weapon-that-goes-all-the-way-throu)

Why are they labelled with 10K views though they are both sitting on around mid 9500 views? and if they said 10K, I should have gotten a badge for it?

Can this be explained please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the homepage view has the viewing numbers rounded. So both questions have over 9,500 views, so are rounded up to 10k in the list.

You will get the badge when the actual number of views is hits 10,000.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, that explains heaps. :)